# How to handle a url differently if it has params and when it doesnt in next.js

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a special case where we have some listings with search with various params like date, cost, etc. How the system is built is users can also share these searches which are stored as URL params.
So currently our getServerSideProps would check the URL and based on params construct the data fetching requests and then generate the pages. But without the params the data is relatively stable and can be statically generated. Is there a way, without changing the URL to generate a static version with ISR and a dynamic one with ssr based on URL params. Also in case ISR is not possible is there a way to cache the API data only on server side without loading the module in client bundle?

Comment: _"Is there a way, without changing the URL to generate a static version with ISR and a dynamic one with ssr based on URL params"_ - They would need to be different pages. A page can't have 2 different rendering methods at the same time. Have you considered having the logic for the added query params on the client-side instead? That way you could have a static version always served from the server, but apply the needed changes for the query params on the client.

Comment: actually query params form the data we fetch from our servers, so if we fetch it and then refetch with query params it would essentially mean doing a useless request as that data would be thrown away on client. What I'm thinking of doing is caching just the standard requests without query params so if we have regular URLs that data is readily available

Comment: So it's the same data, just displayed differently? You could filter the data you get from the server in the client-side, instead of fetching it again.

Comment: Unfortunately its not that simple. Our data is fetched from a search engine service which does a lot of things under the hood and then provides the most relevant results. And the user can then paginate through the specific results. So its technically a subset but its not something we can do on client side :(

Comment: Then if you don't want to use SSR for both cases (static vs. dynamic), I can't think of any other solution other than having different pages for each case.